# vcards in MS dynamics crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

Is there any way to export/send a vcard of the contact from MS dynamics CRM 2011?

I met some builts for CRM 3 and 4, but there hasn't said anything  about CRM 2011.

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the desired effect you are looking for? If you install the outlook client you can chose to sync the contacts you want to have as outlook contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was mentioned in a comment, but you can do this using the Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook client.  This will allow you to synchronize the contact records that a user owns and once they are synched to Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook, you can export them out as a vCard using the steps below, noting that these steps come from this KB article, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290840 .  Although this KB article was written for older versions of Microsoft Outlook, the steps will still work in newer versions of Outlook.

How to create a vCard
Use the following steps to create a vCard: 
1.In a Contact folder, click to select the contact for which you want a vCard.
2.On the File menu, click Save As.
3.In the Save file as type box, click to select VCARD Files (*.vcf).
4.In the Save In box, select the folder where you want to save the vCard file, and then click Save.
This creates a vCard file with the same name as that of the Contact.

Another good reference with videos of creating and exporting vCards is in this support article - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-and-export-vCards-to-Outlook-contacts-9af7e16e-61e3-45f4-8c19-a3842333005a .  There are  ways to add buttons and commands to create and export out vCards from Microsoft Dynamics CRM directly, but I'd just use the built in functionality that comes with Outlook (which is the base of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Outlook client) as it is quick, easy, and something users are likely to adopt without needing to spend extra for development time.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing out of the box that I am aware of.  When you say builds I assume you mean code.  If so, you might consider writing a Plugin which integrates code from the these two links:

*Sample: Send an Email*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh210217.aspx

*.NET vCard API for creating and parsing vCards*
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16030/NET-vCard-API-for-creating-and-parsing-vCards

Comment: Yes, I realize this is a late reply, however at the time there were 0 answers.